# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'. > Compilation failed

Tags: java, android, execution

I was about to make a simple game just for educational purposes but I got a weird Gradle error when I'm trying to launch the game.

My source code:

[image: source code]

[Build errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpmDP.png)

I of course Googled the error but because my lack of experience I didn't found anything that solved my problem. Thanks in Advance

Naomi,

Comment: Can you post build.gradle and errors shown in dialog below this screen?

Comment: I edited it my post thanks

Comment: And build.grade file?

Comment: I think that's all I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is with package name `com.mlgfappy.420`, numbers are possible causing problem. Create new project without numbers in package and try same code.

Comment: There we go! Thank you very much my friend.